# Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <form> in <div>

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, dynamically-generated, point-of-sale

I'm using node v21.4.0, and nextjs v14.0.3
How to fix it, does anyone know?

the problem arose when I generated a random string and called useEffect on the product page to generate a random string for the SKU, when I refreshed an error code appeared like this
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error